# Include initial position with CSS Steps

Tags: css

I'm using css steps to create a "light board" you could say.
So there's a column of 18 divs that act as a "bulb".
The animation moves a div behind it that acts as the "lit up bulb "

My keyframes are set as:

```
@keyframes strobe{
    to{
        transform:translateX(1800%);
    }
}
```

And my animation is set as:

```
animation:strobe 2s steps(18, start) infinite;
```

Currently the animation never includes it's original position. (I also tried using 0% - 100% for the keyframes)

How can I include the initial position in the steps? And why is it currently not?

Included a fiddle for reference. Still working on responsive, so it doesn't show as 18 divs across.

https://jsfiddle.net/btxffgfj/

Comment: Very nicely created!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around with your fiddle, I tried changing `start` to `end` and that seems to work.

```
animation:strobe 2s steps(18, end) infinite;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/msnbu1ho/)